Selecting elements in Chrome Extension Popup
I'm working on a Google Chrome extension, and I have the HTML of the popup. I have an element called #switch, but document.querySelector('#switch') isn't working as a selector. It just returns null.
Any ideas on what to do?
    document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function() {
      let switchElement = document.querySelector('#switch')
      console.log(switchElement)
      switchElement.addEventListener('change', () => {
        console.log(switchElement)
      })
    })

I tried adding an event listener for DOM CONTENT LOADED, but that didn't work.
Here is my HTML:
    <!DOCTYPE html>
    <html lang='en'>
    <head>
      <link rel='stylesheet' href='https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Poppins'/>
      <link href='style.css' rel='stylesheet' type='text/css' />
      <style>
        body {
          font-family: 'Poppins';
          width: 300px;
        }
      </style>
    </head>
    <body>
      <h3>Extension is <span id='status'>active</span>.</h3>
      <form id='settings'>
        <input type='checkbox' id='switch'>
        <label for='switch'>Switch all links to target='_blank'</label>
      </form>
      <script src='script.js'></script>
    </body>
    </html>

And manifest.json:
    {
      "manifest_version": 3,
      "name": "Link Inspector",
      "description": "An easy way to detect whether or not links will open in a new tab.",
      "version": "1.0.0",
      "action": {
        "default_popup": "index.html",
        "default_icon": "personalwebsitefavicon.png"
      },
      "permissions": [
        "activeTab"
      ],
      "content_scripts": [
        {
          "matches": ["<all_urls>"],
          "js": ["script.js"]
        }
      ]
    }

and script.js


The files are:

index.html
manifest.json
script.js


@woxxom please view the edited post containing all of the code.

Remove content_scripts. Note that the popup is a separate window so it has its own separate devtools: right-click inside the popup and select "inspect" in the menu.
